# Modulation of data bits into complex symbols in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

In communication theory, a modulator takes the input sequence and and maps it to some complex numbers. In MATLAB the following commands can do that.

```
data = randi([0 1],96,1);
hModulator = comm.PSKModulator(16,'BitInput',true);
modData = step(hModulator, data);
```

My question, is regarding the last step. Why is a step function able to do this mapping. In particular this step function represents the step response.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `step(H,X)` used here has nothing to do with the step function. It modulates the input data `X` with the modulator object `H`, as described [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.qpskmodulator.step.html). See also [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/gs/system-objects-methods.html#btsx3d1-3).

Comment: So step in the communication toolbox doesn't mean the step response? I have seen it in another context in the communication toolbox too,  step(chanObj, txSig) which is supposed to be, from my understanding in communication theory, convolution between a transmit signal and channel gains. Do you have an idea what it means here? @Matt L.

Comment: @Tyrone: It simply modulates the signal `X` according to the specifications of the object `H`.

Comment: In another context, other than modulation, I found that the command step(X,H) filters input signal X through a MIMO channel object, H. What I don't understand is how the same function step can be used in multiple places with different meaning? @Matt L.

Comment: @Tyrone: As you said, `step(H,X)` is context dependent. It is no simple function but a *method*, processing the data `X` as defined by the object `H`. See [this link](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/gs/system-objects-methods.html#btsx3d1-3).